# Azure Devops Kubernetes@1 login

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I want to login onto an AKS cluster and run kubectl commands.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops) I can login

```yaml
steps:    
- task: Kubernetes@1
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'aks-xxx'
    command: 'login'

- bash: |
    kubectl get pod
```

The login is succesfull but the bash script is not:

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup api.mycluster.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

In bash I can also see that the config file on `$KUBECONFIG` is almost empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a private cluster. See [Create a private Azure Kubernetes Service cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters) for details.

Kubectl is a kubernetes control client. It is an external connectivity provider to connect with our kubernetes cluster. We can't connect with the private cluster externally. See [Options for connecting to the private cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/aks/private-clusters#options-for-connecting-to-the-private-cluster) for details.

> The API server endpoint has no public IP address. To manage the API
> server, you'll need to use a VM that has access to the AKS cluster's
> Azure Virtual Network (VNet).

There are several options for establishing network connectivity to the private cluster.

> - Create a VM in the same Azure Virtual Network (VNet) as the AKS cluster.
> - Use a VM in a separate network and set up Virtual network peering. See the section below for more information on this option.
> - Use an Express Route or VPN connection.
> - Use the AKS command invoke feature.
> - Use a private endpoint connection.

So, you can try to setup and use a self hosted agent on the VM within the same Azure Virtual Network (VNet) as the AKS cluster.

Alternately, create a new public cluster and then try it again. Test the scenario and it works as expected in my side:
[image]